# Managing N languages in PosgtreSQL DBs

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, internationalization, fastapi

Currently have a project where we use:

- FastAPI microservices
- sqlalchemy
- PGDB
- React app as internal tool (contains the "CMS")

The type of data we hold are various health programs - weekly training plans consisting of trainings consisting of exercises etc.; it’s a handful but pretty standard.

Currently we opted for `hstore` for i18n as depicted below in a simple example:

```
class TrainingModel(Base, TimeModel):  
    __tablename__ = "Training"
    name_i18n = Column(
        MutableDict.as_mutable(HSTORE),
        nullable=False,
        default=get_default_hstore,
    )
```

Honestly it’s really OK but it adds so much maintenance over time to our UI for the custom CMS to manage languages. Our logic is the same but I want a PM to manage N languages without worrying about bumping into issues with the content logic i.e. you create a new program once in our internal React app and a separate team handles languages without caring about the quirks of inner admin tools.

Translation software like Phrase and Lokalise seem to be great at managing yaml files etc. but can they be used in a good way to translate DB content?

I understand different projects different needs but this seems like a standard problem so decided to ask :)

Answer (score -2):

Managing multilingual content in your FastAPI microservices effectively includes:

Using CMS that is specifically created for translations.
Utilizing a content API to integrate your microservices with the CMS.
Using translation tools to automate translations, such as Phrase or Lokalise.
Using localization frameworks in your FastAPI project to make it simple to consume translations.
By separating content management from application logic, this method makes it easier for non-technical individuals to manage translations.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Not even remotely helpful to be honest - you have rephrased my question as an answer; a bit like a GPT model - don’t take that personally. I want someone who has been knee deep in this and has experience on the implementation side.